# How can I create a temporary instance of a docker image and execute a command on the instance within an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multiple build and deploy pipelines for my application (User Interface, Internal APIs, External APIs, etc...).  I have another build pipeline for my automated tests (which use Node JS, Nightwatch-API, Cucumber, etc..) that builds a Docker image and pushes it to the Container registry.

I want to be able to pull the testing image into my deployment pipelines and execute the appropriate test script command (i.e. npm run test:InternalAPIs).  My test scripts will publish the results to a separate system.  I am trying to find the best way to execute the automated testing from within the deployment pipeline.

This seems like it should be an easy task within the pipeline build, I just cannot find the task that does what I need.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you reviewed the YAML documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write a bash script for it, and then run the script with the [`Bash@3` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops).

Alternatively, you could make use of built in tasks, such as [`Docker@2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) and [`npm@1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops).

Refer to [Microsoft's documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops) for more details.

**Edit**: You can create a temporary instance of the docker image with the `docker run` command.